# Find the minimum length of the large square box so that all the four suitcases can be put into the box without any overlapping

Tags: python, python-3.x

Four persons A, B, C and D are on a trip. Each of the four have one square shaped suitcase

with them. They want to pack their suitcases into a large square box. The suitcases and the

large box are cuboids with a square base and the heights of the large box as well as the four

suitcases are exactly the same. Hence the concern is only about the side (length) of the large

square box. Your task is to find the minimum length of the large square box so that all the four suitcases can be put into the box without any overlapping.

Input Format

The first line of the input contains four space separated integers indicating the lengths of the suitcases of A, B, C and D respectively

Output Format

Display a single integer indicating the length of the large square box required

Example:

Input:

2 2 2 2

Output:

4

I have tried the given code and I am getting passed in all public test cases but getting failed 3 out of 4  private test cases.

```
n=input().split()
st=[]
for i in n:
  st.append(int(i)**2)
  
for  y in range(sum(st)):
  if y**2 >= sum(st):
    print (y,end="")
    break
```

Please tell me where I am wrong.[image: Click here to see]

Comment: is this a homework task?

Comment: Yes but I have shown my attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lengthSuitcase = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
lengthSuitcase.sort()
for i in range(len(lengthSuitcase)):
    sum = lengthSuitcase[-1] + lengthSuitcase[-2]

print(sum)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

As it is a homework problem, I won't give you a full solution, but I will let you know why it is failing, which is what you asked, right?

Consider the following case:

Suppose you only have `2` suitcases for simplicity (you can also consider 2 more of size 1, everything still holds), and moreover the dimensions are `3` and `2` and suppose your box is of size `4`. Now your argument claims that the boxes fit, since `4^2 = 16 > 13 = 3^2 + 2^2`. However, it is really easy to see that this is not true, as if you put `3x3` suitcase inside of the box, you will only have `1` unit of length from each side, making it impossible to put suitcase of length `2`.

This is what you should focus on.

Comment: oh come on, I already had that typed out. Nevermind, this is the problem.